MariaDB - Where any JSON value within array is between 2 dates
I am looking to search a JSON array in a WHERE to find ANY dates matching between 2 dates.
I am able to match the first matching value using the below. However I would like to find if any of the values are between the 2 dates - ideally in a single query
SELECT *
FROM company_customers
WHERE ( JSON_VALUE( data, '$.call_dates.*.next') BETWEEN '2024/06/10' AND '2024/06/20' )

Example data:
{
 "call_dates":{
    "97":{
      "next":"2024/06/27"
    },
    "2":{
      "next":"2024/06/14"
    }
  }
}

I would like to know if any of the dates within the above JSON at the specific path are between 2 given dates.
I have looked into JSON_SEARCH but there doesn't seem to be a way to search for values between 2 dates.

So, you're trying to get the second value from data which is "2024/06/14" using that query, correct?

@FanoFN Yes, we want to check all values, regardless if it is 1 or 10 to see if any are between the given date.

Take a look at this https://dbfiddle.uk/QZB1nYTl

You can use JSON_TABLE for this:
select distinct c.*
from company_customers c
  join JSON_TABLE(c.data, '$.call_dates.*.next' COLUMNS(d date PATH '$')) as q 
where d between '2024-06-10' AND '2024-06-20';

See dbfiddle

Thanks, this should work however I'm currently on MariaDB 10.3 which doesn't support it. We have plans to upgrade at some point, but can't use this until we do.
